# cmake install multiple version of the same library

Tags: c, cmake, shared-libraries

I am trying to have a scheme with my library that is coherent and usable/reusable.

I work in a team where we work with continuous integration but sometimes I need to use old version of the same library. That's because some part of the software are not updated for using the new version.

I'm actually in the middle of a headache understanding how to use cmake for having something like this:

```
PATH/Library/Processor/Library_X/Version/static_library_and_includes
```

Where Library is a common name where to put my stuff
Processor could be attiny24, atmega, lxpXXXX, etc
Library_X is the name of the library
Version a progressive number from 0 to X
static_library_and_includes the static libraries built within that cmake module and the include files needed for using it.

How can I do this using cmake?
I work with different microprocessor crosscompiling with gcc. This is not a problem.
I work with static library, this is not a problem.
I can install them in the right directory. Not a problem
I can't ask the executable to link to the right .a file. Sometimes cmake pick the right one, sometimes not. 
Can you please give me a hint on how you guys do it?
thank in advance

Andrea

Comment: "Sometimes cmake pick the right one, sometimes not." << How do you tell it where to look?

Comment: Hey there, I stumbled across this and was wondering the exact same thing. I think I found a reasonable way of doing it, please see the examples available here - https://github.com/pr0g/cmake-examples/tree/master/examples/static-versioned - I've yet to write up a full description of what's going on but for now, if you're familiar with CMake it should hopefully be possible to digest some of it.

Answer (score 1):

See the search paths here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure .

CMake will find packages in directories named `name*`, so you can install to `<prefix>/FizzBuzz-1.0.0` and `<prefix>/FizzBuzz-2.0.0`.

As long as each as a correct `ConfigVersion.cmake` file, it should do what you want.